# How to change format of output in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query:

```
select max(run_date) 
    as run_date 
    from vv_flag
    where flag = 'Y'";
```

This query is giving me `NULL` as a result.
However, I want the result to be:

```
result = 0000-00-00 **[YYYY-MM-DD]**
```

Comment: Hi @ashmita, it's probably a wise idea not to _want_ MySQL to give you NULL dates in that format. How MySQL handles "zero dates" has changed in recent versions and also depends on runtime configuration so you can run into unexpected behaviour depending the environment. Instead, handle the null values on the application layer.

Comment: you may want to look at case statements in mysql as well

Comment: " it's probably a wise idea not to want MySQL to give you NULL dates in that format." @marekful read the question with care then you notice the query is **giving him the NULL result** and he is **looking** for a other result... Topicstarter i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide example data and expected results.